# Trouble with filtering posts using WP_Query & dates stored as Meta values

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I am having difficulty filtering date values using WP_Query and meta values that are dates. I have a custom post type and meta values for each post, two of the meta values are dates: `event_start_date` and `event_end_date`. My front-end code is working great until I require the query to only show posts where `event_start_date >= today`

I have 5 custom posts that I'm testing with, event_start_date values are below (each has the meta values stored as DateTime objects in the DB which I've edited below for sake of readability) :

1. 2012-04-03
2. 2012-04-10
3. 2012-04-11
4. 2012-04-17
5. 2017-03-29

What is currently being displayed is all posts (matching the custom post type) irrespective of the date of the post. My code below is adapted from this [Codex Link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) on WP_Query and using the rules from this [Codex Link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) on meta_query:

```
$args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'event' ,
            'posts_per_page' => $numberOfPosts, //declared variable
            'meta_key'       => 'event_start_date',
            'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
            'order'          => 'ASC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'event_start_date',
                    'value'   => '2017-01-01', //I've hard-coded this to test with
                    'compare' => '>=',
                ),
            )
        );
$listings = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I considered that my compare operator could be the wrong way around, so I tried "<=" when I do this I get "No listing found" error.

**Edit**

After implementing the helpful answer below, the problem persisted, it turns out that the meta_query doesn't like the date being stored as an object. I updated how my meta_values were stored and tested again and all works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `type` argument set to `DATE` to the `meta_query` array.

The query needs to know the type of the items to compare.

```
'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'event_start_date',
                'value'   => '2017-01-01', //I've hard-coded this to test with
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type'    => 'DATE'
            ),
        )
```

You will find all details for the meta_query parameter [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

Hope it works after !

Comment: Thanks @Benoti, I had tried this and it makes no difference (I've even copied & pasted your example as a test) still shows "No listings found"

Comment: if you use meta_key argument outside of the meta_query array this will display posts where the custom field key is 'event_start_date', regardless of the custom field value. Try to remove it and use only the meta_query array.

Comment: Just tried it, no change: `$args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'event' ,
   //'posts_per_page' => $numberOfPosts,
            //'meta_key'       => 'event_start_date',
            'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
            'order'          => 'ASC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'event_start_date',
                    'value'   => $today, //I've hard-coded this to test with
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'type'    => 'DATE'
                ),
            )
  );`

Comment: Did you try with the example un my given link that display posts where the custom field key is a set date and the custom field value is now. Displays only posts which date has not passed.

$args = array(
 'post_type'    => 'event',
 'meta_key'     => 'event_date',
 'meta_value'   => date( "Ymd" ), // change to how "event date" is stored
 'meta_compare' => '>',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

Comment: Now it just shows all posts. I've tried to use an if statement and loop rather but that shows all posts as well.. This is really frustrating :(

Comment: I've just tested it and your code works fine for me in a pre_get_posts action (only set meta_query). Did you try to var_dump($args) to be sure that all the values are set ?

Comment: Ok, please don't kill me here: the post data is being pulled from a MSSQL DB and the dates stored as objects, which worked perfectly fine except with this meta_query. I changed my MSSQL connection string to store dates as strings and that has made a difference. Using the example from the link works perfectly now. Thank you for your patience

Comment: Good, I was just thinking to ask you "why not treat the data as a string and not as a date". It would have put you on the track.

Comment: I'm not even going to mention how long I've spent on this :-/ it's weird that the WP_Query can't handle it, at least I know for future reference! Thanks